# Solving Recurrence with Generating Function

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have the following recurrence:

$r_n = 4r_{n-1} + 6r_{n-2} \text{ where } r_0 = 1 \text{ and } r_1 = 3$

---

Next, I write my generating function, $R(x)$:

$$
\begin{align}
R(x)*(1 - 4x - 6x^2) &= r_0 + (r_0 -4*r_1)x + 0*x^2 + ...\\
R(x)*(1 - 4x - 6x^2) &= 1 + (1 - 4*3)x = 1 - 11x
\end{align}
$$

Then, I find my roots...and they are ridiculous.  I've done it 4 times now, and I'm convinced my error lies in the setup.

Either way, I wind up with the following generating function, which is wrong at $n=1$ and thereafter, but seems to be off by a factor of $-5$ at $n=1$ and $11$ at $n=2$, yielding $\{1,-15,66,...\}$ (so there seems to be some correspondence...):

$$
(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2\sqrt{10}}) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{6}{2-\sqrt{10}})^n x^n + (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{2\sqrt{10}})\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{6}{2+\sqrt{10}})^n
$$

I'm not sure where the mistake is.  I am pretty sure about the roots (inverse of the coefficients in the sums) at least (maybe there is some other error, but I double checked them with Wolfram Alpha)...

---

Where might I be going wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't it be $1 - 4x - 6x^2$ instead of $x^2 - 4x - 6$ ?

Comment: I think that is what I have written, isn't it?  $ R(x)*(1-4x-6x^2)$ , 4th line?

Comment: Or are you saying it is the other way around?  I'll try it out.

Comment: I think you should have ended up with $R(x)(1-4x-6x^2)=1-x$. Where you wrote $(1−4∗3)$, you should have written $(4\cdot1-1\cdot3)$. It’s still quite a mess to work out the answer. Mathematica says $r_n=\frac{\left(\sqrt{10}-1\right) \left(2-\sqrt{10}\right)^n+\left(1+\sqrt{10}\right) \left(2+\sqrt{10}\right)^n}{2 \sqrt{10}}$, if I didn’t mistype anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally,
suppose
$r_n = ar_{n-1} + br_{n-2}
$
with
$r_0$ and $r_1$ given.

Let
$R(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r_n x^n
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
xR(x)
&=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r_n x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r_n x^{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r_{n-1} x^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
x^2R(x)
&=x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r_n x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r_n x^{n++2}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} r_{n-2} x^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
R(x)-axR(x)-bx^2R(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r_n x^n
-a\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r_{n-1} x^{n}
-b\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} r_{n-2} x^{n}\\
&=(r_0+r_1x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} r_n x^n)
-a(r_0x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} r_{n-1} x^{n})
-b\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} r_{n-2} x^{n}\\
&=r_0+r_1x-ar_0x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}  x^n(r_n-ar_{n-1}-br_{n-2})\\
&=r_0+x(r_1-ar_0)
\qquad\text{since }r_n-ar_{n-1}-br_{n-2}=0\\
\text{or}\\
R(x)(1-ax-bx^2)
&=r_0+x(r_1-ar_0)\\
\text{or}\\
R(x)
&=\dfrac{r_0+x(r_1-ar_0)}{1-ax-bx^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Write
$1-ax-bx^2
=(1-ux)(1-vx)
$,
then use partial fractions
to get $R(x)$.

(added later)

We have

$\begin{array}\\
R(x)
&=\dfrac{r_0+x(r_1-ar_0)}{1-ax-bx^2}\\
&=\dfrac{p+xq}{(1-ux)(1-vx)}
\qquad\text{where } p = r_0, q = r_1-ar_0\\
&=\dfrac{p+qx}{u-v}\left(-\dfrac{v}{1-v x}+\dfrac{u}{1-u x}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{p}{u-v}\left(-\dfrac{v}{1-v x}+\dfrac{u}{1-u x}\right)
+\dfrac{qx}{u-v}\left(-\dfrac{v}{1-v x}+\dfrac{u}{1-u x}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

We have
$\dfrac{u}{1-u x}
=u\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} u^nx^n
$
and similarly for $v$.
This will enable you
to get the $r_n$.

(end of addition)

This generalizes immediately
to a general linear recurrence,
with the usual caveats about
repeated roots.

As is often the case
in my answers,
absolutely nothing here
is original.

Comment: I think that is what I've got.  I keep getting stuck at $1-4x-6x^2$...then when I split it into roots and solve for partial fractions, It turns into a nightmare I haven't been able to solve yet.  Doing it on wolfram at the moment.  This is along the same lines as the textbook, but more robust and generically applicable.  Thank you, this is great content.

Comment: Write $1-4x-6x^2 = (1-ux)(1-vx)$ and leave it in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: I added an additional explanation.

Answer (score 3):

One way to proceed is by the characteristic polynomial to yield a general solution: $r_n=4r_{n-1}+6r_{n-2}$ is analogous to solving

$r^n=4r^{n-1}+6r^{n-2}$

or better yet:

$r^2=4r+6$

etc. etc.

But explicitly for your purposes:

$r_0=1$ and $r_1=3$. So we take the linear recurrence and consider the formal power series:

$$r(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r_nx^n=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r_nx^n=1+3x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}r_nx^n$$

But we have a particular recurrence to satisfy! So:

$$1+3x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}r_nx^n=1+3x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(4r_{n-1}+6r_{n-2})x^n=1+3x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}4r_{n-1}x^n+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}6r_{n-2}x^n$$

However, we have that: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}4r_{n-1}x^n=3x\cdot4\cdot\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}r_{n-1}x^{n-1}=12x\cdot r(x)$.

Can you express the following in terms of $r(x)$?: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}6r_{n-2}x^n$

Once you have this, it will require only elementary algebra to solve for $r(x)$.

Comment: I like the way you are doing it better than my book.  I think I've just found the answer ($R(x)(1-4x - 6x^2) = (r_0 + (r_1 - 4*r_0)x)$, where I had switched $r_1$ and $r_0$), where we are supposed to use partial fractions to finish everything off.  Anyways, your version is *much* easier and more effective.

Comment: Nvm. I still can't get the book method to work out. but your method does.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: Those are not the roots. The roots of $r^2-4r-6=0$ are $r=\frac12(4\pm\sqrt{16+24})=\frac12(4\pm\sqrt{40})=2\pm\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: @martycohen I didn't actually put any roots anywhere in my solution?

Comment: You have $r0=1$ and $r_1 = 3$.

Comment: that is given by hypothesis. $r_0$ and $r_1$ are $1,3$ respectively...